# Match all in a full text search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, pattern-matching

Using PostgreSQL 9.4, is there anyway that we can specify the `tsquery` to match all?

I have tried:

```
SELECT 'a fat cat sat on a mat and ate a fat rat'::tsvector @@ '*'::tsquery;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It returns `false`.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: @dezso the reason I do so I can input '*' as parameter instead of writing different query based on different parameter.

Comment: That sounds like a very nice performance sink :)  On the other hand, I could not figure out a good solution for you.

Comment: @dezso yeah, I feel the same way. I think it's better to add additional full text search query instead.

Comment: `word | ! word`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap you expression in a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  CASE $1 WHEN '*' THEN TRUE
       ELSE some_tsvector_column @@ $1::tsquery END;
```

This way you can pass `'*'` to disable the filter or any other valid tsquery string to actually filter.

Comment: yeah, this is a simple and understandable solution. Thanks :)